# Android selecting top microphone

Tags: android

How to select top microphone as audio source for recording audio in android.

Now I am using `MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER` as audio source but its not taking top mic for recording.

Answer (score 0):

The [developer documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource.html) lists the supported audio sources. I am unsure what you mean with "top microphone" however I think you should use `MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC`.

Comment: "top microphone" means microphone at the top of the device

Comment: I want to select top microphone as audio source.

Comment: If you use `MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC` the top microphone is used. Did you try that?

Comment: Which device are you using?

Comment: Samsung s4 has as far as i know only one external microphone. There is no "top micro".

Comment: please check the device. it has two microphones

Comment: @SinoKD, I know this is an old question, but you have found an answer?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used audioSource = `MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC` and channelConfig=`AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO`. Then choosing the RIGHT channel input which receive sound from TOP MIC on *HUAWEI Mate10/Mate9*.

Anyway this method is relate to the hardware, **your code only works on specific model**